# Office.js Performance: How much should I put into one Excel.run function?

Tags: office-js, excel-2016

**I'm working with some large spreadsheets (~30,000 rows) and running into some performance issues and have some of the following performance related questions:**

How much can I, or better yet should I, cram into one `Excel.run` function? What are things I need to consider to determine when to break things out into more than one `Excel.run` call?

In general, how many ranges should I create inside one call?

How big of ranges should I be using before I need to perhaps split up one large range into multiple smaller ranges?

Will calling `await ctx.sync()` more or less often do anything to help in relation to this?

**EDIT:**
This question was motivated by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44424045/3806701

Comment: Could you please explain the -1 so I can do better in the future? Thanks.

Comment: It's a very good question.  It takes a fairly long answer to do it justice, though, so let me try to get to it in a few day with a detailed answer.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks so much for your time and help.

Comment: Generally, is it better to have `Excel.run` **only once** in my top level function (and pass ctx down to nested functions) or is it better to use `Excel.run` **inside each nested function** or does it matter?

Comment: apologies for not responding sooner, I had every intention to get back to this thread, but it fell off my radar.  Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for not getting back to this thread sooner.

Several observations:

1. If you are manipulating a large number of **ranges** (ranges are special), you definitely want to do them in as large of blocks as possible (e.g., set values as one giant array on a single range, rather than set values cell by cell and create a bunch of Range objects).  The creation of *any* new API object is not cheap, but Excel Ranges are *particularly* not cheap.  There are also some performance issues that are being currently investigated by the team, I should be able to share more once we've finished the investigation.
2. In terms of the internal implementation, you can think `Excel.run` as task container (maybe like a `"using"` statement in C#)?  And with Ranges in particular, if you go over a couple thousand (you can try it experimentally), things do start slowing down considerably.  So from that perspective, you do want to release your `Excel.run` sooner rather than later (don't do a 10-minute pause waiting for user input in it), and -- until we have a workaround per the investigation I mention above -- you probably do want to keep your `Excel.run`-s reasonably small, to let that memory footprint decrease.
3. That being said, unless you are creating 1000s upon 1000s of API objects, in normal circumstances each "context.sync" or "Excel.run" is a process-boundary or network roundtrip.  And so from that perspective, passing down the context to helper functions is preferable to having several different independenly-awaited-upon Excel.run-s.

For more information, I encourage you to read [Building Office Add-ins using Office.js](https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins/), a book by Yours Truly (but with all profits to charity, so that I don't have to feel guilty when I recommend it to folks :-)).  There is a long (11 pages) section on the internal implementation if you are curious, and for Ranges in particular, you may find it interesting to read "*A special (but common) case: objects without IDs*".  You may also find the section on "*A more complex context.sync example*" useful, particularly around my prescribed pattern for "*Splitting work across multiple subroutines*"

Hope this helps!