# Office.js Excel: Improve performance when writing rows with formatting

Tags: office-js, excel-2016

I can write 25000 rows x 3 columns of plain text in under .3 seconds which is fantastic.

However, as soon as I add more than plain text (formatting, formulas, cell coloring, conditional formatting, columnWidth adjustments, etc) it takes dramatically longer to finish.

For example, I wrote the same 25000 rows (x 1 column) with `range.getCell(i, 0).format.fill.color = 'yellow'` and it took 31.223 seconds, even using `suspendApiCalculationUntilNextSync()`.

What can I do to get better write performance when writing rows with formatting to Excel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The are two angles to answer this question from.

First, the **longer-term**

1. First, we are looking into making an API [no ETA yet, but it *is* being actively investigated] that should make it possible to feed a 2D array of formats into a Range (much as you can do with ".values" today, rather than having to individually create ranges and only set one cell at a time).  That should make it much faster when you have a rectangular block of cells and want to set a bunch of formats on it at the same time.
2. If your cells are scattered through the grid, but they are conceptually grouped such that some of them share the same colors/formatting, another forthcoming API will allows you to create multi-area Ranges would also allow you to speed up processing.  If memory serves from VBA/VSTO, the sweet-spot is creating a multi-area range object comprised of ~30 individual ranges (e.g., "A1, B7:B9, C11, A4, ..."), and setting their format in one go.  This should also help.

Now, to the **shorter-term workaround**:  if you are referencing the CDN and are on a newer-ish build of Office (probably just "current channel" should suffice), you should be able to see a dramatic improvement by **disposing ranges that you don't need**.

A bit of background first.  When you do `Excel.run(...)`, any Ranges that you make use of inside that callback get tracked for the duration of the `run`, so that they can be adjusted when new rows/columns are added/deleted.  This process takes memory, and while it's not perceptable in most cases, it will dramatically slow Excel down if you create 1000s of Ranges.  With formatting, if you're individually formatting different cells to be different colors, and if your starting range is sufficiently large, you might well get into the 1000s.  Moreover, this includes *any* ranges you create, even intermediary ones (e.g., if you do `var rangeXYZ = originalRange.getCell(0,0).getResizedRange(1,1).getIntersection(somethingElse)`, not only will you have created the `rangeXYZ` range, but you will also have created two nameless intermediary ranges, one for `originalRange.getCell(0,0)`, and another for the resized range.  These ranges will still persist throughout the whole duration of the `Excel.run`, even though you'll never access them again!  Of course, the good news is that *at the end*, we will indeed garbage-collect all these uneeded ranges when the `Excel.run` is done, but your code will still be running slow within the `Excel.run`, which is exactly what your question is about.

So: as I mentioned, starting in newer builds (and no-op-ing on older ones), you can call `.untrack()` on the Range to indicate that you won't need it be tracked longer-term.  For convenience, the call to ".untrack()" returns the object itself, so that you can chain it as follows:

```
var rangeXYZ = originalRange
    .getCell(0,0).untrack()
    .getResizedRange(1,1).untrack()
    .getIntersection(somethingElse).untrack();
rangeXYZ.format.fill.color = "yellow"
```

Note the `.untrack()` on each of the intermediary ranges, as well as on the "rangeXYZ" itself.  Any range marked for untracking will be disposed at an opporunte moment during the processing of `context.sync()`.  You can still keep using the Range *before* `context.sync()`, but trying to use it after the `context.sync()` will throw an error.  Essentially, think of `untrack()` as marking the object for early garbage collection on the next `context.sync()`.

Your mileage will vary, but on the example that I used, the performance improved from 13.7 seconds to 5.7 seconds, i.e., a 2.5x performance gain, when formatting a range of 100x100 cells  You can see the code diff here:  https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-snippets/pull/184/files#diff-4bec6e2366b688602d12011ad3b0f2ef.  As you can see, it's very easy to sprinkle in the `.untrack()` calls, and the improvement can be dramatic.

Best!

~ Michael

Comment: I have not come across `.untrack()` yet, that's fantastic, thank you. Almost 4 times faster in my case, down to 8 seconds.

Comment: @cs_pupil, glad it helped :-).  We'll get it documented soon.

Comment: @Zlatkovsky, any suggestions for writing ranges that span many columns (i.e. 100 - 200 columns with formatting?) Writing rows is getting better, but it doesn't seem to scale linearly when more columns are added. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a range for as many cells as possible and then call below code once :

```
range.format.fill.color = 'yellow'
```

If you cannot create a big contiguous range, try to batch as many below code calls as possible within one `context.sync()`

```
range.format.fill.color='yellow'
```

Comment: Thanks. Your first suggestion might work if I were coloring every single cell, but I generally am only coloring specific cells that match a condition. I also assign the fill color in a for loop, and then only call `ctx.sync()` once at the very end.

Comment: what is the condition that you are looking for? is it something you can get with specialCells?

Comment: I'm not sure office.js has specialCells. The value written in the cell came from a server and may have one of 3 warnings attached as metadata. I color the cell based on the warning, if there is one.

Comment: we do have specialCells in preview,thats why I was asking :)